# L-function at s=5 with D=-4?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, l-functions

I want to know the value of $L(5,-4)$. Recall that
$$
L(s,D)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{D}{n}\right) n^{-s}.
$$
I would like a reference with computations of $L(5,D)$, or more generally, of $L(s,D)$ with $s$ and odd natural number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, $D=-4$ is equivalent to $D=-1$, and your symbol is just $\pm1$ depending on the resiude of $n$ modulo 4, so $$L(5,-4)=1-3^{-5}+5^{-5}-7^{-5}+\dots$$ This is known to be $5\pi^5/1536$. A reference for this and other special values of $L$-functions is the section titled Other Power Series in Jolley's book, Summation of Series, a Dover paperback.

For this particular series, Jolley cites page 501 of J Edwards, Differential Calculus, published by Macmillan in 1938.

Comment: This is the right value of $L(5,-4)$. However, I was looking for a general formula for $L(5,D)$ with $D<0$ a fundamental discriminant.

Comment: I note that you asked this question a few weeks ago at MathOverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84812/values-of-dirichlet-l-funcions-at-natural-numbers. I don't have anything to add to the answers you got there, other than what you might be able to track down from references in Jolley.

Comment: Don't worry. It's really curios to me that there are not places with explicit computation of this kind of numbers. My other question was more general, I was interested in one specific case. Thanks again.